# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element error invoking click on followers link within Instagram with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am building an Instagram bot using selenium, and I want to click on my followers to open the complete list of followers. The problem is, I always get the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

I tried locating the element by its Xpath, class name and CSS selector but neither of those worked. I found a post that recommended the following method, which also did not work:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("followers").click()
```

The strangest part is, once the DevTools are open in the same browser, all of the methods I used worked, i.e. opened my list of followers. I am using Microsoft Edge Version 85.0.564.51 btw.

What am I missing here? If needed, I can provide more code.

Comment: Is the page finished rendering/loading when you try to find the element?

Comment: Yes it is. I use `WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)`.

Comment: I forgot to add that we're missing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

- 1st method

The followers element in HTML code is an hyperlink tag :

`<a class="-nal3 " href="/[PROFILE_ID]/followers/" tabindex="0"><span class="g47SY " title="237">237</span> followers</a>`

You can actually go to this URL :

`driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/[PROFILE_ID]/followers/")`

- 2nd method

Your method should work with this xpath instead

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'followers')]").click()`

Comment: I tried both of these, but neither of them worked for me. The first method simply returns my profile page again and the second method leads to a `TimeoutException`. Using the `CSS_SELECTOR` worked for me however.

Answer (score 0):

On [instagram](/questions/tagged/instagram) the link of **followers** is as follows:

```
<a class="-nal3 " href="/PCy/followers/" tabindex="0">
    <span class="g47SY " title="999">999</span> 
    " followers"
</a>
```

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='/followers/'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'followers')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I actually always use WebDriverWait  in combination with `element_to_be_clickable()`. Using the `CSS_SELECTOR` worked for me (thank you), but using the `XPATH` leads to a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: Could you please also explain how you derived at the `CSS_SELECTOR` which you provided? I usually copy the selector by right-clicking on the respective element in the DevTools, but by doing this I derive at a different selector.